# Plot only nodes of a specific date for a social network in R using igraph

Tags: r

I have a social network graph in R using igraph based on a Twitter dataset. Each node represents a specific tweet with a date stamp associated with it. Can someone give me the basic commands in R to plot only those nodes that occur on a specific date?

Here is part of my code that defines the vertices:

```
set.seed(1492)
tweets <- delete.vertices(netg, which(degree(netg)<1)) #remove isolates
V(rt_graph)$size <- centralization.degree(rt_graph)$res #degree 
centrality
cfg <- cluster_fast_greedy(rt_graph)
V(rt_graph)$community <- cfg$membership
plot(rt_graph, vertex.size=5, vertex.label=NA, main="igraph plot")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming date is one the parameters:

`V(rt_graph)<-V(rt_graph)[V(rt_graph)$date=='<your date>']`